# Swift efficient data loading

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I have a web service it retuns me news according to the `categoryID`.I want to load news related to all news at ones. What is the most efficient way to do this? I am using swift. currlently I am doing like this.

`

```
for(i=0 ; i<cat.count ;i++)
{

 self.loadCat(cat[i]["catID"])
}
```

then in my load category method im checking the current id and load the content to seperate arrays

`

```
func loadCat(String:id)
{
  serviceCall()
 if id==1
 {
    self.news.append(currentArray)
 }
 else if id==2
 { 
   self.sports.append(currentArray)
 }

 else is id==3
 {
    self.world.append(currentArray)
  }
```

it takes long time to load all data into seperate Arrays when I have like 10 categories. How can I make this faster. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: use case  replace if , else if

Answer (score 1):

You can use GCD to request concurrently:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.you.downloadCats", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)) {
    // add your request here, don't forget to dispatch to main queue
}
```

Comment: whats this com.you.downloadCats?

Comment: @user1960169 it's just an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You may also change your code,

put every category into an array of objects. Let's say it's

```
var categories = [Category]().     //news,sports,world
```

then, in your for loop change

```
self.loadCat(cat[i]["catID"])
```

to `self.loadCat(cat[i])`

```
func loadCat(Category:category){
categories[category] += currentArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if your data has to be downloaded in a particular order, but you can try this way if you dont need it in order

```
    let sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(2); //depending how many downloads you want to go at once
    for i in 0..<cat.count  {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

            dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

            //download here, order of execution will not be guaranteed
            self.loadCat(cat[i]["catID"]) //maybe pass i as a parameter inside so you know which element of the for loop your are dealing with

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        })
    }
```

if you change how your `loadCats` works, you can maybe preserve the order

Comment: Thanks can you explain me this line? let sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(2);

Comment: What's the semaphore inside the loop for?

Comment: I get only the last array filled. other 2 arrays become empty

Comment: `let sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(2);` is creating a semaphore that allows 2 actions through at a time, so basically 2 of your downloads would go at the same time instead of all of them at once. im not sure why your array would be incomplete, at the end of each dispatch_sync you should refresh your view to display the new data, maybe its just not displaying properly? or maybe you are checking the data before its all finished